# fpscr register is not updated when enabling floating point exceptions on arm7, SIGFPE not generated

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, floating-point, arm

fpscr register is not updated and SIGFPE is not generated.  This was tested on an NVidia Shield Tablet and a 1st gen Nexus 7.

```
feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO | FE_INVALID | FE_OVERFLOW);
```

The implementation calls code, which eventually executes this assembly:

```
  asm _volatile__("vmsr fpscr,%0" : :"ri" (fpscr));
  ; disassembly follows
  ldr r3, [r11, #-8] 
  vmsr fpscr, r3
```

`vmsr fpscr` does not update.  It remains 0x20000010 when it should be updated to 0x20000710.

Tested with `-mfloat-abi=soft` and `-mfloat-abi=softfp`.

What can I conclude?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ARM ARM has this to say about all the exception-trapping bits in FPSCR:

> [...]. This bit is RW only if the implementation supports the trapping of floating-point exceptions. In an implementation that does not support floating-point exception trapping, this bit is RES0.

The Tegra K1 SoC in the SHIELD Tablet has Cortex-A15 CPUs, which [don't support VFP exception trapping](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0438i/CDEFCBDC.html#Chdfifdc).

The Tegra 3 SoC in the original Nexus 7 has Cortex-A9 CPUs (with the VFP+NEON implementation), which [don't support](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0409i/Chdfifdc.html) [VFP exception trapping](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0409i/Chdcaegb.html)

What is particularly unhelpful is that from userspace you can't even access the MVFR0 feature register to find this out programatically.

I think you can only conclude that you don't have any hardware which supports trapped exceptions ;)